# Hide new folder option in telerik editor file uploading

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radeditor

I am using telerik rad editor in my projct. To add image I am using Image manager,while click on Image manager it opens the pop up where I can upload multiple images to the specified folder. It also showing me image editing option in same popup. My requirement is I don't want to show default image folder to user  and don't want any image editing. I also want to hide add new folder option. please help me. If you have any sample code. Please share with me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize the dialogs so that the elements you do not want visible to the user are not, e.g. by setting their display CSS property to none or by editing the markup. See this demo for an example:
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/externaldialogspath/defaultcs.aspx. Note that just removing controls is likely to cause an error so you should test your custom dialog carefully.

Regarding the folder you show - in order to upload images you need to access the folder, so the files will be shown to the user. You can try implementing a custom provider to hide certain files, see this demo on the matter: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/dbfilebrowsercontentprovider/defaultcs.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

i think the below url help you through this hope this helps:)
http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/editor/radeditor---image-manager---removing-commands.aspx

Comment: Friend I already visited this but no luck, I don't want any css patch for this. I want to disable these with help of code. I hope it will be fixed through C# code with help of telerik classes. but I am not able to find any such solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
<telerik:RadFileExplorer ID="RadFileExplorer1" Height="410px" Width="400px" TreePaneWidth="150px"
runat="Server" EnableOpenFile="false" AllowPaging="true" VisibleControls="TreeView,Toolbar,Grid,AddressBox"/>
```

for more info see this link http://goo.gl/k9LMuR